# Gradle download dependency merge into maven local repository?

Tags: maven, gradle

It's the 1st time to use gradle in our project and we're using the local maven repository.
Now I have a question:
Is it possible to make gradle download dependency merging into local maven repository automatically? 
Is there any configuration or plugin to resolve?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32159148/5006866

Answer (score 5):

Short answer is: no way!

Gradle has its own cache, although it can read the maven local repo like this:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

If some dependency not found in maven local repo, Gradle will download it from maven central and cache it in ~/.gradle/caches/...

see http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/cache_dependencies_into_local_maven_repository_from_gradle

Answer (score 1):

Although [Gradle has its own cache](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/cache-dependencies-into-local-maven-repository-from-gradle/7525/15), the files are stored in a structure similar to that of Maven local repository. To update Maven local with dependencies from Gradle cache, here are the task and configuration for that (tested with Gradle 7.5):

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
 // Place your dependencies here
}

build {
    finalizedBy 'cacheToMavenLocal'
}

task cacheToMavenLocal(type: Copy) {
    from new File(gradle.gradleUserHomeDir, 'caches/modules-2/files-2.1')
    into repositories.mavenLocal().url
    eachFile {
        List<String> parts = it.path.split('/')
        it.path = [parts[0].replace('.','/'), parts[1], parts[2], parts[4]].join('/')
    }
    includeEmptyDirs false
}
```

The task was copied and adapted from [@Adrodoc55's answer on Gradle forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/need-a-gradle-task-to-copy-all-dependencies-to-a-local-maven-repo/13397/15).

---

As an addendum:

Using the [maven-publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) plugin's [`publishToMavenLocal`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:tasks) task, Gradle will publish the project's build artifacts (e.g. resulting .jar file) to Maven local.

```
gradle publishToMavenLocal
```