# Gradle does not use the Maven Local Repository for a new dependency

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have Maven with `M2_HOME` defined to `/Users/manuelj/apache/maven/3.2.5`

I have the `settings.xml` file, located on `/Users/manuelj/apache/maven/3.2.5/conf/settings.xml`

where I have the following declared:

```
<localRepository>/Users/manuelj/apache/maven/repository</localRepository>
```

Until here with Maven all works fine. Any new dependency goes there.

I have a project based with Gradle, among many things in my *build.gradle*, exists the following:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

version = '1.0.0'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
   mavenLocal()
   mavenCentral()
}
… more
```

Until here, all works fine too. Code compile, executes well.

My confusion is the following.

According with my understanding is that Gradle's `mavenLocal()` should use the same path than `<localRepository>` defined on Maven's `settings.xml` file.

Now confirming that in the Maven local repository exists some dependencies already downloaded.

When I execute for example gradle build, I did realize that

- If a dependency already exists from the Maven Local Repository, it is used from there.
- If a dependency does not exist from the Maven Local Repository Gradle download the new dependency to: `/Users/manuelj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1`

I want that the new dependency go directly to the same Maven Local Repository.

Therefore, what extra configuration is need it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752463/gradle-downloading-dependency-into-cache-instead-of-maven-repository

Comment: Thanks. Sad about the lack of support for this.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue, have you found any solution?

Comment: @jhandei no so far ...

Answer (score 69):

## Resolving Dependencies From Local Maven Repository

Gradle is able to resolve artifacts stored in the local Maven repository (usually `~/.m2/repository`) via [mavenLocal()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:maven_repo).

According to the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:maven_repo), `mavenLocal()` is resolved like this:

> Gradle uses the same logic as Maven to identify the location of your local Maven cache. If a local repository location is defined in a `settings.xml`, this location will be used. The `settings.xml` in `USER_HOME/.m2` takes precedence over the `settings.xml` in `M2_HOME/conf`. If no `settings.xml`is available, Gradle uses the default location `USER_HOME/.m2/repository`.

To resolve artifacts from a non-standard local Maven repository, you can use the following configuration in your `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url '/Users/manuelj/apache/maven/repository'
    }
}
```

(From: [How does Gradle resolve the directory of the local maven repository?](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/mavenlocal-how-does-gradle-resolve-the-directory-of-the-local-maven-repository/4407))

Custom Maven repositories are documented [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/repository_types.html#sub:maven_repo).

## Storing Artifacts in the Local Maven Repository

Gradle stores resolved dependencies in its own [Dependency Cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_cache.html). The dependency cache is so much more than just a simple Maven artifact repository:

- Stores binaries (jars), artifact meta-data (POM, Ivy files), dependency resolution results and module descriptors.
- Tuned for performance, for example shorter file paths.
- De-duplicates artifacts: Same binaries are stored only once.
- Tracks where a dependency came from. A dependency resolved from `jcenter()` might be different to the one resolved from `mavenCentral()`.
- Automatic, time and usage bases, cache cleanup.

Artifacts produced by the build can be easily pushed to the local Maven repository via `publishToMavenLocal` task contributed by the [Maven Publish Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html).

But what about resolved dependencies? For the aforementioned reasons, Gradle cannot store dependencies in the local Maven repository. There's currently no built-in functionality to even publish dependencies to the Maven's local repository from the build script. So what are your options:

- Create a shell script that does the necessary legwork. [Daniel Dietrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1110815) once wrote one and published it on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/danieldietrich/status/1146362741571145729?s=20) ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/danieldietrich/76e480f3fb903bdeaac5b1fb007ab5ac)).
- Use an artifact proxy like [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss) or [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/). Maven and Gradle can be configured to consume dependencies from the same proxy. This setup is quite common in professional environments and my personal preference.

Comment: Thanks by the reply, Remember I want that the new dependencies gotten through Gradle go to the Maven Local Repository. Check the comment in my question. There is a link to other question. Sadly there is no solution yet.

Comment: Neither this answer nor the answer below works for me (gradle version 4.8.1). I have an artifact in the local repo but gradle doesn't seem to see it, whereas maven itself has no problem with it. Adding `apply plugin: 'maven'` doesn't help

Comment: @thokuest I am waiting for the version 4.9 to be available in AUR in hopes that the one I have is just broken (;

Comment: @Jezor Gradle 4.9 has just been released: https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/release-notes.html

Comment: Does not work and gives me this error: 
> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'app\build.gradle'

Comment: @Jörg see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69197871/5006866

Answer (score 25):

Use

```
mavenLocal()
```

for example:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M1'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.4')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

I am using Gradle 3.5

Comment: Nowadays you should not use mavenLocal() !! -> https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:case-for-maven-local

Comment: mavenLocal() has its uses and purposes, so saying it should not be used is incorrect. When testing multiple dependencies, mavenLocal() is very useful. On a typical CI box, the local maven repo SHOULD BE clean/empty so you are never building with local artifacts, but when testing locally it is fine to use mavenLocal().

Answer (score 16):

This drove me to drink.

If I do `mvn install` for a project having a version of `1.1.1.SNAPSHOT` it goes into my local maven repository (~/m2/repository/...) with no errors.  However, Gradle using `mavenLocal()` will not attempt to locate it in the local maven repository (having used `./gradlew bootRun --debug` and inspecting the logs).

If I change the version to `1.1.1-SNAPSHOT` (note the dash), then Gradle will attempt, and will find the repository.

It doesn't make sense to me that Maven finds this to be a valid version number for local use, but Gradle completely ignores it.

Comment: OMG. Thanks for sharing - I was debugging for someting like this for quite some time. Gradle is so much of a pointless "Reinvent the wheel" tool. Insead of people contributing to make maven better, they create their own tool with its own flaws, bells and whistles...

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue because I'm working on a legacy project where I need to run my build with the `sudo gradle build` command. The build involves copying XSD files, which require root permissions. I opted not to employ the solutions of the previous answers because I didn't want to change the build file; I didn't want to accidentally checkin my `build.gradle` changes. What I found was that Gradle was checking for `mavenLocal` in the `/var/root/.m2` folder. My solution was to copy `/Users/me/.m2/settings.xml` to `/var/root/.m2` and add a line for the `localRepository` to point back to my `/Users/me/.m2` folder. A sample line and where to add it is:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>/Users/me/.m2/repository</localRepository>
  <profiles>
```

Comment: Interesting, I will try to check it in other PC