# Cross module dependencies with Gradle and mavenLocal

Tags: android, gradle

My project is an old android application (`module-front`) with modules (`module-shared`) that used to be published on maven.
I have an access to source code of the module and I want to store my module in my mavenLocal.
My directory structure :

```
/project
    /module-front
        build.gradle
    /module-shared
        build.gradle
    build.gradle
```

My `module-front` gradle file has a dependency on the published (but removed) module-shared :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    // Android properties here
}

dependencies {
    ext {/* Versions here */}

    compile group: 'module-shared group', name: 'module-shared name', version: moduleSharedVersion

    // compile and testCompile here
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apt {
    // apt here
}
```

ModuleSharedVersion is defined in my root gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }

}

allprojects {
    ext {
        moduleSharedVersion= '2.1'
    }
    version = '1.4.8h'
    group = 'myGroup'
}
```

**Problem starts here:**
Now I want my module-shared to be stored in mavenLocal so my `module-front` might access it :

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'maven'

version = '2.1'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenInstaller {
            repository(url: mavenLocal().url)
            pom.groupId = 'module-shared group'
            pom.artifactId = 'module-shared name'
            pom.version = version
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

This is my attempt to store it in mavenLocal inspired from multiple posts ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107205/gradle-does-not-use-the-maven-local-repository-for-a-new-dependency)) which doesn't work...
I don't know much about gradle, not enough to fix it tbh.

Please tell me if you need any other file that might be important to understand/answer.
Thanks :)

Comment: aren't you be using plugin 'maven' in your last gradle snippet ?

Comment: edited my post but it didn't fix :/