# Could not find com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0

Tags: android, maven, gradle, jcenter

jCenter may be shut down right now.
I knew jCenter was already out of support.
But our app is still using it.

After jCenter closed, we can not build for android.
So we use mavenCentral instead of jCenter.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
-       jCenter()
+       mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

and tried to build my project.
I encountered below error.

```
$ ./gradlew assemble 

Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.2.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

As far as I searched on maven repository, mavenCentral doesn't have twitter-sdk.
https://search.maven.org/search?q=com.twitter.sdk.android

I know twitter-sdk is already deprecated. but our project is highly depending on it.
We should resolve this problem provisionally.

I don't know hot to get jar file.
Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: @Robert I know the risk for using this artifact, but we should build our project anyway. I already tried mvnrepository but decilned because of 403 forbidden.

Comment: have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core` is EOL and thus should not be used anymore (no support, may contain security problems, ..). The list of repositories this artifact is contained in can be found here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twitter.sdk.android/twitter-core?repo=springio-libs-release

If you have tried all repos mentioned on this site without success you can only build the artifact from source yourself: https://github.com/twitter-archive/twitter-kit-android

Unfortunately the Git repository has no releases or tags, so you can't and also the commit log does not contain any info about released versions. But the master branch seem to contain version 3.3.0 (second last commit was "Prepare for May release." which was 3.3.0).

Build the project and install it to your local Maven repo and then [add the local Maven repository to your gradle repo list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44380673/150978).

Comment: I created my own maven repo and uploaded aar/pom file to it.I worked so far. thx.

Comment: @yn1043 hello, I'm new on react native, can you help me how to create my own ?

Comment: how did you create the repo could you please help?